Create Realm in available only for the temp admin ID - not for the new users created?
I have installed keycloak from container version 26.07. With the use of default id admin, which is temporary, I have created a new realm 'realma', created user 'usera' and assgined 'manage-realm' access for both 'master' and 'realma'. In fact, I have assigned all available roles to 'usersa'. I am not seeing 'create realm' option for 'usera', which is available for the temp id 'admin'. As the temp id 'admin' has to be deleted, I can't create new realms in the future. How to solve this?
I tried assigning soles, clients and client scopes - nothing working.

I think you should create the usera inside the master realm.

The manage-realm role allows users to manage a specific realm but does not grant the ability to create new realms. The admin role in the master realm is required for realm creation.
The solution would be to grant admin role in the master realm (via the realm-management client in the master realm) to usera.

Log in with the Temporary Admin Account

Use the temporary admin account created during Keycloak installation.
Navigate to the Keycloak Admin Console.

Switch to the master Realm

In the top-left dropdown, select the master realm.
The master realm is the administrative realm that controls access to creating and managing other realms.

Assign the admin Role to usera

Go to Users > usera > Role Mappings.
Under Client Roles, select realm-management as the client.
Assign the admin role to usera.
(This role grants full administrative privileges for the master realm, including realm creation.)

Log out of the Keycloak Admin Console.
Log in using the credentials for usera.
Check if the Create Realm option is now visible.

(It should appear in the top-right corner of the admin dashboard.)

Once you’ve confirmed that usera can create realms:


Log in as usera.
Switch to the master realm and delete the temporary admin account.

